# How do I connect external sensors to android mobile?

Tags: android, connect, sensors

I want to connect a number of external sensors (temperature sensor,pressure sensor , etc..)  to an android mobile. What are the different ways for this? How do I read data from these sensors? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You need device like `Arduino` to connect sensors to android, which then connected via network and can communicate with each other.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a cheap Arduino Nano from China, with a cheap HC-06 BlueTooth module, also from China.
Then read the values in a 10 mt range.
Or you could use a networked solution, to read values all over the Web.

Answer (score 0):

Probably a bit late for this, but you should really try the IOIO-OTG board. Its purpose is to do exactly what you asked for: connect Android devices to sensors and actuators. The Android device can connect to the IOIO-OTG board via Bluetooth or USB/OTG cable. The programming is made in JAVA ( e.g. by using Eclipse ADT). Just google IOIO-OTG for more details or ask here and I can help you.

Have fun!